# Android :Get Key press, Key release Events out of Activity Screen

Tags: android, android-activity, keypress, keyevent

I wanted to get Get Key press, Key release Events out of my Activity Screen 
i.e ex When i am in Android Native Home Screen and if i Press Search KEY i need to fire my API..Is it Possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i am in Android Native Home Screen and if i Press Search KEY i need to fire my API..Is it Possible??

No. Key events are generally only delivered to the foreground activity. The two exceptions are the CAMERA button (on those few devices that have one) and the MEDIA button (found on headsets) -- those are sent as broadcast `Intents` if the foreground activity does not consume the event.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the SEARCH button, but BACK button you can override.

As I know HOME button can't be override.

Maybe consider using MENU button to display option menu?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
            //your method
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Im my case my Activity is in background,so will be not getting callback to onKeyDown..:(